# Stability of densly defined $C_{0}$-semigroup

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

Let $(S(t))_{t \geq 0}$ be a $C_{0}$-semigroup on $H$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space. Suppose that $(S(t))_{t \geq 0}$ satisfies the following estimate on a dense subspace on $H$
$$||S(t)x||_H \leq e^{-t}||x||_H.$$
Can this estimate be extended for any $x \in H$?.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, let $x \in H$ and $D$ be the dense subspace and $(x_n) \subset D$ such that $x_n \to x$ in $H$, since $S(t) \in L(H,H)$ then $S(t)x_n \to S(t)x$ in $H$. Therefore, $\|S(t)x_n\| \to \|S(t)x\|$. Passing to the limit the inequality $\|S(t)x_n\|_H \leq e^{-t}\|x_n\|_{H}$  we obtain the desired since $\|x_n\| \rightarrow \|x\|$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer.

Comment: @Gustave If you are satisfied with the answer, then consider clicking the option to "accept" it, so that the question does not show up as "unanswered"